# Can we remotly control iPhone connected to remote machine to trust developer (for provisioning profile)?

Tags: ios, iphone, appium-ios, trust, facebook-webdriver

I'm working on remote mac machine using Team Viewer.
At times I need to build WebDriverAgent project on that machine and manually trust the WebDriverAgentRunner and Initegration app on the connected iPhone.

But remotely I cannot interact with the iPhone and need someone physically present there to tap on "Trust" from iPhone settings.

Is there any way I can control iPhone?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there are [several apps that offer this](https://www.apowersoft.com/control-iphone-pc.html).

One app I recommend (no affiliation) is **ApowerMirror**. [Download link](https://download.apowersoft.com/down.php?softid=apowermirror). It allows you to remotely control the iPhone so you can "trust" the developer.

Note: You will need to be on the same WiFi as the iPhone.

Alternatively, if you can't be on the same WiFi, you can connect the iPhone to the Remote Controlled computer and control the iPhone from the Remote Controlled Computer, so it goes:

iPhone -> RC computer -> Your computer

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, however Veency is for Jailbroken iPhone; We are not allowed to jailbreak those iPhones. And Apower is only for mirrioing. So both solution are not workable for me.